# Interactive Map without Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a huge plan of a site (the plan is just a picture), the problem is that Google Maps, can't have access to it, so I need to add markers in this picture (Plan), My question how to that ? how to make a picture interactive ? how to add markers ?

Really I have no idea, I saw indoor of Google Maps, but it's not what my custmer need.

Thank's ! 
this is a small example [image]

Answer (score 0):

you may give this library a try or see its demo here: https://leafletjs.com
it's a pure javascript library that may be used with any web platforms

wish it to be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please explain why leafletjs fits the OP's needs.